# Jquery validation prior ajax form submission for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Though a common question I searched around and tried all hit and trial .. but no avail .. still the issue for jquery validation persist before ajax call.. The form is getting submitting without any validation

Please provide any info where i may be getting wrong

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


    $('#myform').validate({ 

                    rules: {
                        objective: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 150
                        },
                    },

                submitHandler: function ()
                    {
                            var dataString = $("#myform").serializeArray();
                            $("#flash").show();
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "xyz.php",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: dataString,
                                cache: false,
                                async: false,
                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert('error');
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $("#flash").hide();
                                        $('#info').html(data.objective);
                                        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                                    $("#objective").focus();
                                }
                            });
                            return false;

                    }
            });

    });
</script>
```

html

```
<form class="form-horizontal " name="myform" id="myform"  action="include/process.php" method="post">


          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="objective" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Objective</label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="objective" name="objective" placeholder="Objective" ></textarea>
               </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <button type="submit"  id="editbtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success  pull-right hovertip"  data-toggle="tooltip"  data-original-title=" Add ">Add Data</button>
              </div>
          </div>

      </form>
```

There are three more similar forms on the same page...

Comment: I'm sorry what's the problem exactly?

Comment: @atjoshi, please indicate what the problem you're facing is with the 3 forms.  Using #myForm should limit your calls above to only the form you are working with unless you are using the same ID for more than one form, etc.

Comment: all form are having its different ids... so presented this demo form submitting one at a time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `e.preventDefault` in the beginning of your click handler.

```
$("#editbtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of the code.
}
```

It will prevent your form from being sent without going through your js code.

Comment: something its working but on second click .. first click is attaching validtor to form and second click is taking validation for the same .. functional for second click .

Answer (score 0):

You could do what @Romain said or change the HTML to:

```
<input type="button" id="editbtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success  pull-right hovertip"  data-toggle="tooltip"  data-original-title=" Add " value="Add Data" />
```

So the form doesn't submit

Comment: Now its preventing submit totally

Comment: @atjoshi yes, you could add `$("#myform").submit();` to submit the form when is required

Comment: I have edited the changes and removed the cick event totally just using the submitHnadler .. Its workig fine but .. the edit button to populate the input text is not working on second clcick .. anyidea

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to trigger the submit via JavaScript, then you can type the button as 'button', instead of submit:

```
<button type="button"  id="editbtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success  pull-right hovertip"  data-toggle="tooltip"  data-original-title=" Add ">Add Data</button>
```

This will prevent the default submit action from executing, and let you handle everything via your onclick method.